# Prompting user for connection parameters to SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, security, sql-server, authentication

I try to avoid keeping passwords etc. in memory or in plain text anywhere. But I am on a huge time crunch and this will only be used internally this week then probably won't get touched again. I just want to make sure this is secure and if not, what the risk is.

I'm mostly concerned about the password sitting in memory. I'm not sanitizing data but for this particular case it isn't needed.

My specific questions are:

1. From a security perspective, would this code be acceptable in a SQL Importer?
2. Besides data sanitation, is there a best practice somewhere that I'm missing in this?

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the Server Name. Ex: SQLMASTER"); //Gets the server to connect to, an IP address is also acceptable.
ServerName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter the Database. Ex: Accounts"); //The actual database to use.
DatabaseName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Use Windows authentication? Y/N"); //you will usually use this. 
YesNo = Console.ReadLine();

if (YesNo.ToLower() != "y")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your Username (Domain name may be required). Ex: MyName");
    UserName = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter your Password. Ex: ********");
    Password = ReadPassword();

    //Builds the connection string with the data we collected above. We're going to send this to the SQL Connection. (Username and Password)
    ConnectionString = "Data Source = " + ServerName + "; Initial Catalog = " + DatabaseName + "; User ID = " + UserName + "; Password = " + Password;

    Password = ""; //We do this to clear the password from memory
    UserName = ""; //Clearing username from memory
}
else
{
    //Builds the connection string with the data we collected above. We're going to send this to the SQL Connection. (Windows Authentication)
    ConnectionString = "Data Source = " + ServerName + "; Initial Catalog = " + DatabaseName + "; Integrated Security=SSPI"; //User ID = " + UserName + "; Password = " + Password;
}

//Create a new connection with above connection string
SQLCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
ConnectionString = ""; //Again, doing this to purge the credentials from memory

try
{
   SQLCon.Open();
   Console.WriteLine("\nConnected!\n");
   Console.WriteLine("Working...\n");
   .... etc
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Failed! See console for details");
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: CodeReview is not the proper site for security of memory.

Comment: Less about "Security" and more about usability: if a username or password contains a semicolon then your connection string will be invalid.

Comment: @JackWilsdon Obligatory: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Haha, yeah I know, but this will only be used by IT personell to help migrate/update some data this week. I would hope they would not derp but probably a good idea to sanitize anyway.

Comment: @TylerC "Is this secure" is far too vague a question. Secure against *what*? An external hacker, a rogue developer, human error, the NSA? Once you know what you want to protect against, then you can start figuring out whether your system is secure or not.

Comment: I'm mostly looking for an answer of. Whats the risk of something pulling the password out of memory. For this particular use case, we don't care, but in the future, I'd like to know if this is acceptable connection string code. I tried to keep it generic so it could be reused.

Comment: If someone has access to your machine then there is absolutely 0 security. No point in trying to re-assign the `Password` property -- it doesn't actually remove that string from memory. Storing it as a char array and overwriting each index might be better in that regard but you still have to turn it into a string anyway. Long story short: focus on actually important things, this is pointless.

Comment: This still isn't complete. You've said there was a loop but there isn't any.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Fair enough, won't worry about it then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't matter what *you* do with this code, the `ConnectionString` can always be accessed in the `SqlConnection`.

As a test, here's what you should do:

Launch your application *outside* of Visual Studio. Take a *new* instance of Visual Studio and go to 'Debug' -> 'Attach to Process...' and then locate the process for your programme.

Once you have done this, run your programme until the SQL point, then hit the 'Pause debugging' button in Visual Studio.

Once you have done this, go to the Diagnostic Tools and take a memory snapshot. While it's paused you can view the memory dump of the snapshot.

You should see a record appear in the 'Memory Usage' tab of the diagnostic tools, click the 'Objects (Diff)' link.

[image: Take a snapshot]

A new tab will open with *a lot of fun stuff*, order everything by 'Object Type' and find `SqlConnection`.

Double click your `SqlConnection` line.

[image: Find the root object]

Click the first line (assuming you have one) in the new portion of the window, then click 'Referenced Objects' at the bottom section of the window.

It should show you a bunch of objects, find `SqlConnectionString`, and drill down into it.

You should see several `string` objects. Go ahead and hover each one, one will be your password.

Of course, the `string` object on the `SqlConnection` itself will also be a connection string and have your password in it.

[image: Extract your connection string]

Bottom line: the client computer is **always** compromised in your eyes. You can do no more to secure it at this point, with an instance of Visual Studio (which this can be done more effectively with a separate programme that hides on the client computer) I can view your connection string and extract it with little to no effort required. (This whole process takes ~10 seconds once you have used the 'Break All' on the programme.)

My advice to you: don't take unnecessary security precautions to ensure your work is 'safe in memory' -- there's no such thing. All memory can be dumped, and even if it's only in memory for ~0.00001ms, an attacker can still find it. Just worry about building your application, let the memory security be handled by the user. :)

---

On to the code review:

- `YesNo` is a bad variable name; C# rules are `camelCase` for local members. It should also be named something related to what it does: `windowsCredentials`.
- You say data sanitization isn't important, but what happens if the user enters a semicolon then another `ConnectionString` property? You should *always* validate input.
- You should be `using` the `SQLCon`, not creating it like you are. (`using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))`), same with `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` if/when/where you use them.

### Why?

The `SqlConnection` type is an `IDisposable` - that means, it's capable of being automatically closed and deallocated.

In the case of `SqlConnection`, IIRC there are unmanaged objects that need disposed, cleared and cleaned up before the connection is done. There are resources it uses that are not automatically freed.

If you look at the API of `SqlConnection`, it has a `Close()` method which indicates that it will disconnect from the database and free it's resources. This is important because if you *forget* the `Close()` call, then your database connection will hang open. This has performance implications for your programme, database and network.

So, we use `using (...)` construct for it which is a fancy way of writing:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection();
try
{
    /* Inner code here */
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)connection).Dispose();
}
```

The `Dispose()` method of `SqlConnection` then handles closing and flushing all the connection information.

---

On to *your* requests:

> 1. From a security perspective, would this code be acceptable in a SQL Importer?

As far as security goes - *maybe*. I'm not a security expert, but I would be wary of having no input validation here. At the very least, do not allow input with a semicolon (`;`), as that can totally mess with your connection string.

> 2. Besides data sanitation, is there a best practice somewhere that I'm missing in this?

I mentioned them above, but generally speaking you're trying to solve a problem that we have accepted as a non-issue. Worry about the features of the application, *then* about the security. Your job as a programmer is not to secure the information in RAM, but to secure it:

- On disk / file system
- In the database
- Over the network

Don't worry so much about the password sitting in memory. *Yes,* it's generally safer to keep it in memory as shortly as possible, but that goes along with Single-Responsibility Principle, the Principle of Least Astonishment, etc. Your password (and **all** variables) should be as short-lived as possible. (I.e. Don't do like the old C code used to with 100 variables defined at the top of the file.)

I *have* turned this answer [into a guide on my blog](http://usingprogramming.com/post/2017/01/04/demonstrating-insecurity-of-managed-windows-program-memory) for further explanation.

Comment: Is this just a "fact of life" sort of thing then? Do commercial applications worry about this? If not I won't get too far into it. Also, THANK you for answering this question this way, its exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @TylerC Yes, it's a fact of life. Commercial applications usually don't bother to worry about it at *this* level, that's the responsibility of the user. Your job is to ensure that actual network traffic is encrypted/secured, data access is secured, etc. If the client machine is compromised, **you are not at fault.**

Comment: Just read through it again, can you explain why it would be better to be _using_ the SQLCon instead of the way I'm doing it?

Comment: @TylerC Added an explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Your code fails to escape values in the connection string.  Use the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.  You set properties on it, and it will escape the values as necessary.

For example, if you are unclear how to set properties on an object:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
builder.UserId = "my user id";
// and so on for the other properties
```

I hope that this is fairly self-explanatory, but if there is anything I can explain in more detail, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of integrating the username and password in the connectionstring you should use a [`SqlCredential`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) object. The constructor of the `SqlCredential` class takes a username as a string and the password as a [`SecureString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx).

The resulting `SqlCredential` can the be passed with a connectionstring to the [constructor of the `SqlConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh136722(v=vs.110).aspx).

Sample of reading the password from the console

```
private static SecureString ReadPassword()
{
    var secured = new SecureString();
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);

    while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
    {
        secured.AppendChar(keyInfo.KeyChar);
        keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
    } 

    secured.MakeReadOnly();
    return secured;
}
```

and used like so

```
ConnectionString = "Data Source = " + ServerName + "; Initial Catalog = " + DatabaseName + ";";  
UserName = Console.ReadLine();  
SqlCredential credentials = new SqlCredential(UserName, ReadPassword());
using(SQLCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString, credentials))
{
    try
    {
       SQLCon.Open();
       Console.WriteLine("\nConnected!\n");
       Console.WriteLine("Working...\n");
       .... etc
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Failed! See console for details");
       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

You can for sure do this in a loop for the case that the user entered the wrong username or password, **but** you shoucl restrict the number of tries to a not too high number.

Answer (score 2):

Part of `ConnectionString` repeats. Do the common part once.

You never test the credentials. You should report back the error message if the connection (Open) fails.

As stated in comments, sanitize data.

I bet the string is still in `SQLCon` anyway, otherwize `.Open()` would fail.

Leaving connections open is bad for scale.

Comment: That is a try block not a loop.  User will have to shut down and restart.

Comment: I see what you're saying, very inconvenient (I actually got annoyed when using it because of this.) I will add it into a loop. Thanks!

Comment: 1. I will make that change
2. Test occurs, just not in a loop.
3. I will make that change as well, I know that can become a problem

4. Probably, It might be worth investigating but I see that its not a concern

5. I have a close at the end of the try block

Thanks for the input!